# Dirichlet principle with Neumann boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to prove the Dirichlet principle (Energy is minimum) for this problem:
$$-\Delta u=0 \quad in \quad D\\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=h\quad on \quad \partial D   $$

Solution:
Is it possible to use this :
Let u and v be two solutions then w=u-v is also a solution then $$\Delta w=0 \quad in \quad D\\ \frac{\partial w}{\partial n}=0\quad on \quad \partial D   $$ 
We multiply the equation by w and integrate over D and then apply Green first identity:
$$\iiint_D w\Delta w dx=0\Rightarrow -\iiint_D \nabla w\nabla w dx+\iint_{\partial D}  \frac{\partial w}{\partial n}ds \Rightarrow \\-\iiint_D \nabla w\nabla w dx=0\Rightarrow \iiint_D |\nabla w|^2 dx=0$$ 
$$|\nabla w|^2= |\nabla u-\nabla v|^2=| \nabla u|^2-2|\nabla u|.|\nabla v|-|\nabla u|^2$$
If we use Young inequality then $$|\nabla u|.|\nabla v|\leq \frac{|\nabla u|^2}{2}+\frac{|\nabla v|^2}{2}\Rightarrow -2|\nabla u|.|\nabla v|\geq |\nabla u|^2+|\nabla v|^2$$
$$|\nabla w|^2\geq |\nabla u|^2+|\nabla u|^2+|\nabla v|^2+|\nabla v|^2=2(|\nabla u|^2+|\nabla v|^2)$$
$$\iiint_D |\nabla w|^2 dx\geq 2 \Big(\iiint_D |\nabla u|^2 dx+\iiint_D |\nabla v|^2 dx\Big)\Rightarrow 2 \Big(\iiint_D |\nabla u|^2 dx+\iiint_D |\nabla v|^2 dx\Big)\leq0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\Big(\iiint_D |\nabla u|^2 dx+\iiint_D |\nabla v|^2 dx\Big)\leq0 \Rightarrow E(u)+E(v)\leq0 
\Rightarrow  E(u)\leq-E(v)$$

Is what I did make sense?

Comment: Please pose the problem. Are you minimizing $\int \|\nabla u\|^2dx$ subject to Neuman condition? If so, you need to take another arbitrary function $w$ satisfying Neumann condition and show $E(u)\leq E(w)$. You cannot assume $\Delta w =0$.

Comment: Yes ,I want to show that $E(u)\leq E(w)$ but I wondered if i could do it by using the energy method used in proving the uniqueness.

Comment: In the way I did $\Delta w=0$ because both $\Delta u ,\Delta v=0$

Comment: I meant $v$; you cannot assume $\Delta v=0$. You need to take some arbitrary $v$ and show that $E(u)\leq E(v)$. Arguments similar to energy methods will work, but not this. I would look at Evans Chapter 2 proof of Dirichlet principle for Dirichlet conditions and mimic the proof.